# In XSLT, is it normal that a variable set to something like name(..) is computed at time of use?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a couple of trees in my XML and wanted to access one in terms of a name in the other. Here is is called the `tab_name` and it is the parent tag of the current node so I use name(..). That gives me the correct value if I test at the same location where I set the variable.

However, the problem I have is that when I reference $tab_name a few lines below (in the `<xsl:when>` tag) the name(..) is applied to the current context so I get the tag "group" instead of what I would otherwise expect.

```
<xsl:variable name="tab_name" select="name(..)"/>
<legend>
    <xsl:for-each select="/snap/page/body/client/group/*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(.) = $tab_name">  <!-- $tab_name = 'group' here! -->
            ...
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</legend>
```

Is that the normal/expected behavior of XSLT 2.0? I was thinking that the variable would be set in its own for-each context (for-each not shown here) and not the new sub-for-each context.

---

Here are full XSLT and XML documents to reproduce the problem with xmlpatterns (the Qt XML parser).

XSLT (say a.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                              xmlns:snap="snap:snap">

    <xsl:template match="snap">
        <xsl:for-each select="page/body/client/data_field/*">
            Direct name = <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/> [correct, getting 'dog']
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:variable name="tab_name" select="name(..)"/>
                Parent name = <xsl:value-of select="$tab_name"/> [correct, getting 'dog']
                <xsl:message>Message has no side-effects... <xsl:value-of select="$tab_name"/></xsl:message>
                <xsl:for-each select="/snap/page/body/client/group">
                    Inside other for-each tab_name = <xsl:value-of select="$tab_name"/> [incorrect, getting 'client']
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!-- vim: ts=2 sw=2
-->
```

XML (say a.xml):

```
<!DOCTYPE snap>
<snap>
  <page>
    <body layout-name="finball">
      <client>
        <group>
          <cat>Jolly</cat>
          <dog>Bear</dog>
        </group>
        <data_field>
          <cat>
            <div>All about Cats</div>
          </cat>
          <dog>
            <div>All about Dogs</div>
          </dog>
        </data_field>
      </client>
    </body>
  </page>
</snap>
<!--
vim: ts=2 sw=2 et
-->
```

Command I use to reproduce the problem:

```
xmlpatterns a.xsl a.xml
```

The output is incorrect:

```
        Direct name = cat [correct, getting 'cat']

            Parent name = cat [correct, getting 'cat']

                Inside other for-each tab_name = client [incorrect, getting 'client']

        Direct name = dog [correct, getting 'dog']

            Parent name = dog [correct, getting 'dog']

                Inside other for-each tab_name = client [incorrect, getting 'client']
```

---

(As a detail: I'm using Qt XSTL 2.0 implementation, in case it is not normal, then the Qt implementation is what is broken.)

Comment: The 'name()`  within the `for-each` should iterate over the names of the children of the `<group>` tag and not `<group>` itself - unless you have nested `<group>`'s. Could you include a stripped down excerpt your your input XML?

Comment: Yes, I'm not questioning the `name(.)` but the `$tab_name` variable. The variable is `name(..)` so `<group>` is correct, but not what I would expect because the variable was set outside the current `for-each`.

Comment: OK. I get it. This seems to be unexpected behavior due to incorrect lazy evaluation of the variable. Does outputting it (e.g. forcing a direct evaluation `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$tab_name"/></xsl:message>` right after the assignment) change anything?

Comment: Note that I already "fixed" the problem using a template because I know parameters are set properly. But you seem to be saying what I was thinking: lazy evaluation using the wrong parents... Anyway, I'll do a little test to see whether I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a bug in the [Qt XSLT 2.0 processor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xmlprocessing.html). At their website they claim that they only partially support XSLT 2.0. However, this behavior of assigning variables has not changed between 1.0 and 2.0.

> "In XSLT, is it normal that a variable set to something like name(..) is computed at time of use?"

Yes, it is normal that is computed "at the time it is used", to prevent unnecessary overhead. Most processors ([including ours](http://exselt.net), in most cases), will calculate variables once and only when used. However, they must be calculated in light of their declaration context, which is clearly not what's happening here:

> *The declaration of the variable defines its focus and context, not the place where the variable is referenced.*

When I run your input XML and stylesheet XSLT against [Saxon](http://saxonica.com) or [Exselt](http://exselt.net) (or probably any other processor out there that I haven't tried), it gives the following output (outdented and whitelines removed for clarity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Direct name = cat [correct, getting 'dog']
    Parent name = cat [correct, getting 'dog']
        Inside other for-each tab_name = cat [incorrect, getting 'client']
Direct name = dog [correct, getting 'dog']
    Parent name = dog [correct, getting 'dog']
        Inside other for-each tab_name = dog [incorrect, getting 'client']
```

As you can see, it is either always "dog" or always "cat", as it should be.

I suggest [you file a bug](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ReportingBugsInQt) against this processor or, considering it is open source and if you have the time, [help them out to fix](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/issues/?filter=10568) it at the source ;).

Comment: Yeah... I already don't have enough time for my own development... 8-) Thank you for taking the time to test with other processors. Last time I posted a bug about XSLT at Qt, the answer was rather strange, something like "since no one else is affected, we won't fix it." Anyway, I guess I could try again.

Comment: _"as no one else is affected..."_, that _is_ a strange answer. But this looks like such an essential behavior that really ought to be fixed, that I'd say the response will be different this time around.